# Using ECDSA private key in Java with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I'm trying to use ECDSA in Java with BouncyCastle library and the private key I get by reading the pkcs12 file in Java is different than what I see in the PEM file (which I got using openssl). I'm unsure if they should be the same but seems logical. Question is how do I get the same private key in Java using BC from a pkcs12 file as using openssl?

The cert and the key was generated with

```
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out private-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key private-key.pem -out server.pem -days 730              
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in server.pem -inkey private-key.pem -out ecdsaCertificate.p12
```

Java code:

```
 Public static void readCertificateData()
      throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
      FileNotFoundException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

System.out.println("Get KeyStore");
KeyStore pkcs12Store = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");
System.out.println("Read File");
pkcs12Store.load(new FileInputStream(CERT), PASSWORD.toCharArray());

Enumeration aliasEnum = pkcs12Store.aliases();
Key key = null;
Certificate cert = null;

while (aliasEnum.hasMoreElements()) {

      String keyName = (String) aliasEnum.nextElement();
      key = pkcs12Store.getKey(keyName, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
      ECPrivateKey ecKey = (ECPrivateKey) key;

      System.out.println("ecKey : \n" + ecKey.toString());
      System.out.println("privKeyToDER:\n" + privateKeyToDER((PrivateKey) key));
      cert = pkcs12Store.getCertificate(keyName);
      System.out.println("cert2 :\n" + Base64.toBase64String((cert.getEncoded())));

      StringToFile(DIR + "tempCert.pem", "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
              + Base64.toBase64String((cert.getEncoded())) + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n");
      System.out.println("privKey Base64 : " + Base64.toBase64String(key.getEncoded()));
      cert = pkcs12Store.getCertificate(keyName);
}
}
public static String privateKeyToDER(PrivateKey key) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bos));

    pemWriter.writeObject(key);
    pemWriter.close();

    return new String(bos.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "they're different"? How do you know the private keys are different? The files certainly have different formats but the private keys contained therein should be the same.

Comment: Visibly they are in the same format but seem to be different. How can I verify that they are indeed the same?